# Are Restful web services created in axis2/c truly RESTful?

Tags: rest, axis2c

I'm a newbie to RESTful webservices and I'm trying to create a RESTful webservice in one of our previous SOAP based webservice hosted in axis2c which by it's documentation says that one can host both RESTful webservices and SOAP based ones at the same time?

If so will the RESTful webservice be truly RESTful?(My doubts are on this one). I'm finding it hard to find tutorials for building RESTful webservices in axis2c apart from their documentation. If there are some good tutorials out there that you know of please post them.

Comment: You might be interested in this [stack-exchange proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review?referrer=aWNm_PdciyFqjFW8CUacGw2 "code review"). It's almost ready to begin beta, just needs a few more.

Comment: @Victor _ Looks interesting, will be there.

Comment: Update: I moved to WCF RESTful services to try my hand at that. But if someone hopefully points me in the right direction, i'd try my hand @ axis2/c anytime

Answer (score 1):

To determine whether or not a REST service is truly RESTful, one must measure the service against the six constraints of a RESTful Web Service:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer#Constraints

If your web service meets the 5 criteria (one is optional) then the service is truly RESTful.

Comment: Thanks for the link James but I'm still looking from someone who has built a RESTful service on axis2/c to point out some good pointers for me to get started on this. Building it on axis2/c is where i got stuck.

Comment: Sorry, I can only answer your first question:  How to tell is it's RESTful.  I've used Axis with SOAP and can tell you it's an experience I am in no hurry to repeat :)  I can't imagine it being much better with REST.

Comment: Oh then can you suggest other alternatives where I can expose the same service as both RESTful and soap as axis2/c says it can.